# How to compare the sameness of object entries of 2 arrays and how to create a merger of both objects with custom properties of the found same object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, comparison

I am trying to compare 2 objects by their property and the values **Strictly using forloop**. If the value of the "name" or another property matches up with each other, I want to push the property and value to value3.

Once value3 is logged, I want the response like this:

```
{
name: 'dog',
surname: 'good',
skills: 'programming',
age: '22'
},
{
name: 'cat',
surname: 'soft',
skills: 'engineer'
age: '12'
},
{
name: 'elephant',
surname: 'big',
skills: 'programming'
age: '23'
}
```

Here is the code:

```
var values1 = [
    {
    name: 'dog',
    surname: 'good',
    skills: 'programming'
    },
    {
    name: 'cat',
    surname: 'soft',
    skills: 'engineer'
    },
    {
    name: 'elephant',
    surname: 'big',
    skills: 'programming'
    }
]

var values2 = [
    {
    name: 'cat',
    food: 'fish',
    age: '12'
    },
    {
    name: 'elephant',
    food: 'leafs',
    age: '13'
    },
    {
    lastname: 'dog',
    food: 'treats',
    age: '22'
    }
]

// push into this empty object array
var values3 = [{}]

console.log(values3)
```

Comment: ... mustn't it be `age: 13` for the desired `name: 'elephant'` item? And by which rule does `age` get merged into the final item but `food` doesn't? And why is it `lastname: 'dog'` for `values2`'s last item?

Comment: dont worry about ```food``` I just want to compare ```name:``` from the arrays and if they match, then push ```age``` to that. but we do see that there is also ```lastname:``` property but that still has the same value as ```name```

Comment: How should one provide the OP with a valid generic approach, if the question / requirements and even the example code are presented not that precise? For instance the Q. states explicitly ... *"If the value of the "name" or another property matches up with each other"* ... but then the OP changes it in a side comment to ... *"dont worry about `food` I just want to compare `name`"*. Please OP rework your question and specify the exact requirements.

Comment: because if you look at the properties of both, you can see that ```food``` is not in both of the arrays. All I ask is to compare the values and if they do match, push all the properties and values into one new array

Comment: `age` too is not part of each array's items but it gets merged. Again. Specify the exact requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most generic approach which fulfills all of the OP's requirements should be based on [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Its advantage comes with utilizing the additionally passed optional [*initial value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) as kind of configurable collector/accumulator object which will carry all the needed additional information / functions / result. Thus one can provide a reusable function with a customizable context/environment which one can adapt to ones needs.

```js
var values1 = [{
  name: 'dog',
  surname: 'good',
  skills: 'programming',
}, {
  name: 'cat',
  surname: 'soft',
  skills: 'engineer',
}, {
  name: 'elephant',
  surname: 'big',
  skills: 'programming',
}];

var values2 = [{
  name: 'cat',
  food: 'fish',
  age: '12'
}, {
  name: 'elephant',
  food: 'leafs',
  age: '13'
}, {
  lastname: 'dog',
  food: 'treats',
  age: '22'
}];

function mergeItemsOfSameEntry(collector, item) {
  const {
    getSameEntryValue,
    getMergeSubType,
    comparisonItems,
    result
  } = collector;

  const itemValue = getSameEntryValue(item);
  const comparisonItem = comparisonItems
    .find(cItem => getSameEntryValue(cItem) === itemValue);

  if (comparisonItem !== null) {
    result.push({
      ...item,
      ...getMergeSubType(comparisonItem),
    });
  }
  return collector;
}

const values3 = values1.reduce(mergeItemsOfSameEntry, {

  getSameEntryValue: item => item.name ?? item.lastname,
  getMergeSubType: ({ age }) => ({ age }),
  comparisonItems: values2,
  result: [],

}).result;

console.log({ values3 });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the key and value pair, you can do something like this:

```js
var values1 = [
    {
    name: 'dog',
    surname: 'good',
    skills: 'programming'
    },
    {
    name: 'cat',
    surname: 'soft',
    skills: 'engineer'
    },
    {
    name: 'elephant',
    surname: 'big',
    skills: 'programming'
    }
]

var values2 = [
    {
    name: 'cat',
    food: 'fish',
    age: '12'
    },
    {
    name: 'elephant',
    food: 'leafs',
    age: '13'
    },
    {
    lastname: 'dog',
    food: 'treats',
    age: '22'
    }
]

// push into this empty object array
var values3 = [];

values1.forEach(eachValue1Obj => {
  const keys = Object.keys(eachValue1Obj);
  keys.forEach(eachKey => {
    values2.forEach(eachValue2Obj => {
      if (
        eachValue1Obj[eachKey] &&
        eachValue2Obj[eachKey] &&
        eachValue1Obj[eachKey] === eachValue2Obj[eachKey]
      ) {
        const x = {
          key: eachKey,
          value: eachValue1Obj[eachKey]
        };
        values3.push(x)
      }
    })
  })
})

console.log('Values 3 Array ==>', values3);
```

Comment: its slightly similar to what I am asking. 

I want the values3 answer to be 
```{
name: 'dog',
surname: 'good',
skills: 'programming',
age: '22'
},
{
name: 'cat',
surname: 'soft',
skills: 'engineer'
age: '12'
},
{
name: 'elephant',
surname: 'big',
skills: 'programming'
age: '23'
}```

Comment: Without further code review and besides that the result comes not close to what the OP has asked for I want to mention that in my opinion an approach with 3 nested `forEach` loops already is heading into the wrong direction.